# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'(111) even the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists

Tags: mysql, centos7

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' even the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.

Things in hand:

- The my.cnf file is pointed to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.
- The mysql.sock is permitted to be read/executed by the user selected.
- Previously the mysql is working. I had check the log file it said that "Database was not shut down normally".

Things can't do:
The mysql.sock is not downloadable.
I assume the mysql.sock has something wrong with it.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've seen your question frequently, and it's likely that your question has been answered by one of the many existing questions on Stack Overflow. But you don't provide enough information about what you did or what the error was. I suggest you read some (or all) of the answers linked in the column of "Related" questions on the right side of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search the file "my.cnf", usually located in the folder "/etc/mysql/". Create a backup as a precaution.
Edit it like this:

```
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
port     = 3306
basedir  = /usr
```

And, please, verify if your user is allowed to read "mysql.sock".

Comment: The folder is mysql not mysqld should i create mysqld folder?

Answer (score 0):

What functioned me to quit that error is:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /var/run/mysqld
mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld
# ensure that /var/run/mysqld (used for socket and lock files) is writable regardless of the UID our mysqld instance ends up having at runtime
chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld
```

I got this answer in the Dockerfile of mysql 8.0 in hub.docker.com:
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/3362baccb4352bcf0022014f67c1ec7e6808b8c5/8.0/Dockerfile